# Set State of a list

Tags: reactjs, list, state, statelist

When I tried to set the state of my list, I tried two methods.

```
setEatenFoodList(prevList => {
        prevList.unshift(addedFood);
        return prevList;
})
```

This method adds the addedFood two times.

```
setEatenFoodList([...eatenFoodList, addedFood])
```

When this method adds it one time, which is what I want. But, I want to know the difference between these two methods.

Comment: Try `[...prevList].unshift(addedFood)`

Answer (score 0):

As to your last question what both methods are doing are similar with `unshift`
adding the `addedFood` in front of the `eatenFoodList`  array while the in second method `eatenFoodList` is first destructured and then `addedFood` is added.

Need more context on what conditions you are updating the `eatenFoodList` state to find out how the first method is executing twice.

Comment: Hi @nayan , Thanks for anwering my question. To add more context, I wrapped the function `setEatenFoodList` in a ` setTimeout ` in both cases.